# Path variable not being set properly in zsh

Tags: zsh, path, profile

For some reason, my $PATH variable is not being set properly which means I can't run a lot of commands I would like to. Here are the relevant lines from my `.zshrc` file:

```
if [[ -f ~/.profile]]; then
    source ~/.profile
fi
```

Here is my `.profile` file:

```
pathdirs=( 
    ~/.rvm/bin
    /usr/local/heroku/bin
    /usr/local/shar/scala-2.10.0/bin
)

for dir in $pathdirs; do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
        path+=$dir
    fi
done
```

When I echo my $PATH variable, none of these three items shows up. All I get when I run `cat $PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:
/usr/texbin`. Could anyone see if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean. My `.zshrc` is run every time a new shell is open. Within my `.zshrc`, I have a statement that loads my `.profile` where I keep all of my $PATH related needs. What's the confusion?

Comment: What does putting a `echo $dir` right before `path+=...` show you?

Comment: Please don't `cat $PATH`... That sounds dangerous

Comment: In `bash` at least, you need to do `path+=($dir)` rather than `path+=$dir`.

Comment: `.profile` is traditionally read by all Bourne/POSIX-compliant shells.  In which case you'd need `"${pathdirs[@]}"` rather than `$pathdirs`.

Comment: @slm, echoing the $dir variable returns the three bins that I'm trying to add correctly

Comment: @mikeserv, oops! Meant to say that I've been echoing them.

Comment: @Mikel, tried both of your suggestions, unfortunately didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote for another answer:

```
_path_assign() { oFS=$IFS ; IFS=: ; add=$* ; unset P A ; A=
    set -- ${PATH:=$1} ; for p in $add ; do {
        [ -z "${p%-[AP]}" ] && { unset P A
                eval ${p#-}= ; continue ; }
        for d ; do [ -z "${d%"$p"}" ] && break
        done ; } || set -- ${P+$p} $* ${A+$p}
        done ; export PATH="$*" ; IFS=$oFS
}

% PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin
% _path_assign \
    /usr/bin \
    /usr/yes/bin \
    /usr/bin/nope \
    -P \
    /usr/nope/bin \
    /usr/bin \
    -A \
    /nope/usr/bin \
    /usr/nope/bin

% echo $PATH
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
/usr/nope/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/yes/bin:/usr/bin/nope:/nope/usr/bin
```

All arguments following a `-P` are prepended to `$PATH` if they are not already included, and same for `-A` but they're appended. If you want to verify they're actual directories first you can change:

```
|| set -- ${P+$p} $* ${A+$p}
done
```

to:

```
|| { [ -d "$p" ] && set -- ${P+$p} $* ${A+$p}
} ; done
```

You should probably make sure `zsh` handles `$IFS` more portably by just adding:

```
[ "${SHELL##*/}" = "zsh" ] && emulate sh
```

to the first line.

Make those two changes and all of the code you have in your question could be replaced with this function and:

```
test -f ~/.profile && . $_
_path_assign ~/.rvm/bin \
    /usr/local/heroku/bin \
    /usr/local/shar/scala-2.10.0/bin
```